# Is 8086 assembly program and MASM programs are same?

Tags: assembly, masm

I have a task to write MASM program and to run it. But while studying it, I noticed both 8086 assembly codes and MASM codes are same? Is there any difference between them? Can I run both of these programs on emu8086?

Comment: MASM is one of the assemblers that can assemble for 8086.

Comment: emu8086 uses MASM syntax.  Note that emu8086 is a specific program that includes an assembler.  But "8086" is the name of a CPU and architecture; any assembler can make machine code for it, including NASM and GAS which use different directives and even syntax from MASM.  Do not mix up 8086 with emu8086.